# Pass function as parameter to Lambda java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the following method:

```
public String getAllDangerousProductsName(Offer offer){
    return offer.getOfferRows().stream()
           .filter(row -> row.isDangerousGood())
            .map(row -> row.getItemInformation().getOfferTexts().getName())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

I want to reuse this method for row.isBulkyGood(). What I am doing currently is

```
public String getAllBulkyProductsName(Offer offer){
    return offer.getOfferRows().stream()
            .filter(row -> row.isBulkyGood())
            .map(row -> row.getItemInformation().getOfferTexts().getName())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

... which is basically code repetition. Is there a way I can pass the function as method parameter to optimize this to have one method for both the filter condition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass the `Predicate` used in the filter right to the method which is the only thing that differs in the methods.

Assuming `offer.getOfferRows()` returns `List<OfferRow>`, then:

```
public String getAllDangerousProductsName(Offer offer, Predicate<OfferRow> predicate) {
    return offer.getOfferRows().stream()
            .filter(predicate)
            .map(row -> row.getItemInformation().getOfferTexts().getName())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Usage becomes fairly simple:

```
// using lambda expression
String str1 = getAllDangerousProductsName(offer, row -> row.isDangerousGood());
String str2 = getAllDangerousProductsName(offer, row -> row.isBulkyGood());
```

```
// using method reference
String str1 = getAllDangerousProductsName(offer, OfferRow::isDangerousGood);
String str2 = getAllDangerousProductsName(offer, OfferRow::isBulkyGood);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could add a `Predicate<OfferRow>` argument to this method and then use method references `OfferRow::isDangerousGood` or `OfferRow::isBulkyGood`:

```java
public static String getAllProductsNameByPredicate(Offer offer, Predicate<OfferRow> predicate){
    return offer.getOfferRows().stream()
            .filter(predicate)
            .map(row -> row.getName())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}

// invoke with different predicates
getAllProductsNameByPredicate(myOffer, OfferRow::isDangerousGood);
getAllProductsNameByPredicate(myOffer, OfferRow::isBulkyGood);
```

If it is needed to negate the condition of the predicate, [`Predicate.not`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate)) may be used since Java 11.

For Java 8-10, a utility method may be implemented using `Predicate.negate()`:

```java
public static <R> Predicate<R> not(Predicate<R> predicate) {
    return predicate.negate();
}

getAllProductsNameByPredicate(myOffer, not(OfferRow::isDangerousGood));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create a `filterAndJoin`:

```
public String filterAndJoin(Offer offer, Predicate<Row> predicate){
    return offer.getOfferRows().stream()
        .filter(predicate)
        .map(row -> row.getItemInformation().getOfferTexts().getName())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
  }
```

and then change the calls to

```
public String getAllDangerousProductsName(Offer offer){
    return filterAndJoin(offer, Row::isBulkyGood);
}
```